# Output message for missing files with Linux find

Tags: linux, find

I'm hoping someone can help me with a 'find' command. I have a text file containing a list of 4500 filenames, 1 per line. I need to recursively search a directory structure for each file and output a list containing each file name with absolute path. Here is what I have so far:

```
!#/bin/bash
find /mnt/data/tempproj/ -name "some file 001.tga" >> /mnt/data/outlist.txt
find /mnt/data/tempproj/ -name "some file 002.tga" >> /mnt/data/outlist.txt
find /mnt/data/tempproj/ -name "some file 003.tga" >> /mnt/data/outlist.txt
```

Etc etc etc

The problem is that the output list is shorter than the input list by nearly 500 entries, suggesting that a number of files have been moved. I need to output the list with placeholders for each of the missing files which 'find' is not doing by default. In other words, I need to get a list something like this:

```
/mnt/data/tempproj/images/iptc/some file 001.tga
FILE MISSING: some file 002.tga
/mnt/data/tempproj/images/iptc/some file 003.tga
```

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the output of `find` in a variable. if the variable is empty, write the `FILE MISSING` line to the output file, otherwise print the filename.

Comment: That's a little beyond my skillset but I'm researching.

Comment: Didn't ask for free coding services. As I said, I'm researching variables.

Comment: `find_output="$(find /mnt/data/tempproj/ -name 'some file 001.tga')" ; case "${find_output:-NoOutput}" in NoOutput ) echo "not found 'some file 001.tga'" ;; * ) echo "${find_output}" >>  /mnt/data/outlist.txt ;; esac` or similar will get you started (you can also use an `if` test to see if $find_output is empty or not.) Remember to zero out your `/mnt/data/outlist.txt`, as each time you test, you are looking at your first run at the top of the file ;-). Good luck.